# Fluent nHibernate Mapping OneToOne

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have 3 tables:

```
Table1 - Id, Name
Table2 - Id, Name
Table3 - Id, Table2Id, Address
```

Table1 and Table2 have the same Id, and table 3 references this Id on Table2. I am trying to map Table1 so it loads the data in Table 3. Here is what I have tried so far, everything is returning `null` for the Address field:

```
HasOne(x => x.Address).ForeignKey("Id");
HasOne(x => x.Address).ForeignKey("Table2Id").Cascade.Delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

HasOne requires all of the tables to have the same primary key which they don't in this case.  It looks to me like you need to change the mapping to use References:

```
References(x => x.Address).KeyColumn("Id");
```